# Laravel 5.1 delete a specific table using rollback

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, migration, rollback

I am using laravel 5.1 I have 6 table in my project, suppose 
table_1,
table_2,
table_3,
table_4,
table_5,table_6. In this time I need not table_3.My all table are created using migration and all are filled with data, There are no foreign key.Now I want to delete table_3 using rollback, Is it possible? If how?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not just delete the table manually or create a new migration that drops it?

Answer (score 2):

**A new migration that drops the table would be the best solution.** The purpose of migrations is not only to create new database structures, it's also to modify them, and deleting a table is just that, a modification.

Even if it may seem redundant to create a table in one migration and delete it in a subsequent one, this is the best course of action. This way, when distributing the app and running all migrations on another machine, you get a consistent state for the database after all migrations are complete.